# Implementing insertion sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I wanna see if the implementation of the insertion sort is correct.

I first made the loop run 0 to Length - 1

Then the second loop runs from i to 0

Then the if condition will check the current number of array at position j and position j-1
till j-1 is equal to 0

```
void InsertionSort(int* ptr, int Length)
{
    int i = 0;
   
    for (i = 0; i < Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if ((*(ptr + (j-1)) > *(ptr + j)) && (j-1) != -1) 
            {
                int temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0; // Then if the condition satisfy we swap the values
                temp1 = *(ptr + (j-1));
                temp2 = *(ptr + j);
                *(ptr + (j-1)) = temp2;
                *(ptr + j) = temp1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A nice property of insertion sort is that it will only scan the data once if the data is sorted. Your second for-statement is a contradiction for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, the structure of insertion sort is the following

- for each element in ptr.

  - find an out of order element.

    - move it into place among the previous elements. continue from this position.

In your implementation the second for-statement is done prematurely.

Comment: so like I should only iterate on the elements who are less than the previous number, right? i.e,
a[i-1] > a[i]
then swap the position

then after swaping the position if a[i-2] > a[i-1]
then how will be the work flow?